# Google Drive SDK offline access in JavaScript

Tags: google-drive-api

I know the mobile SDKs for Google Drive support offline mode (according to [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files)), but does the JavaScript/web SDK support this as well?  Do end-users have to use Chrome with the Google Drive app from the chrome webstore to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The link you posted was for the Google Drive Android API which is more a way to interface to the Android Drive app, than to Drive itself (although of course, ultimately it's the same thing).

None of the Drive SDKs have any concept of offline working, so this is something you'll need to implement yourself.